# NSString alloc/init generates 'Redefinition of myStr' error....?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I seem to be generating a lot of questions with this one little iPhone app....

I am attempting to stuff an NSMutableArray with NSStrings, and I am working like this:

```
...
NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Jupiter II"]; 
[txtArray addObject: myStr];
[myStr release];

NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Could this be OUR Waffles?"];
// in this second block, the line above generates the error: 'Redefinition of myStr'. Why?
[txtArray addObject: myStr];
[myStr release];
...
```

The first block generates no errors, but the subsequent blocks (identical save for the content of each string object) all generate the error, 'Redefinition of myStr'. Why?

I know that this is going to be a facepalm, but I just gotta know, and get beyond this!

hanks for any and all assistance!

Kind regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove NSString* from the second block:

```
NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Jupiter II"]; 
[txtArray addObject: myStr];
[myStr release];

myStr = [[NSString alloc] ...
```

Each time you write something like `NSString *myStr` you declare new variable - and variable names must be different in the same scope. But you can reuse the same variable to store different objects - as you do in the code above

Comment: Thanks Vlad! Eh, it was pretty obvious once you pointed that out....  ::sigh::

:)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was just for the sake of example, but your first three lines of code can be substituted with:

```
[txtArray addObject:@"Jupiter II"]
```

Also, creating an array of strings is as simple as:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Jupiter II",
                          @"Could this be OUR Waffles",
                          nil];
```